# Not playing audio in voice channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

There is a problem the bot does not play anything I tried debugging it(using print statements) and after calling the `voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()`

After connecting to the VC idk if the code pauses or runs in a infinite loop it does not execute the next line of code.

this is my code for !play

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query):
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
        return

    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    # Connect to voice channel in a separate thread
    voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()


    # Get the URL for the first search result
    results = YoutubeSearch(query, max_results=1).to_dict()
    if not results:
        print("No results found")
        return

    audio_url = "https://www.youtube.com" + results[0]['url_suffix']

    # Create the audio source from the YouTube URL using youtube_dl
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'quiet': True,
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(audio_url, download=False)
        url = info['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url, method='fallback')

    # Play the audio source using the voice client
    voice_client.play(source)

    # Send a message to confirm playback
    await ctx.send(f'Playing {info["title"]}')

    # Disconnect from the voice channel when playback is finished
    while voice_client.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await voice_client.disconnect()
```

I tried running vc.connect in a thread but then im getting an error connect didnt awaited

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems perfectly correct. I think it is because you are using an old version of [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). If you look at the [`changelog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whats_new.html#v1-2-4), there was a bug similar to this in version `1.2.3` and earlier.

You should probably bump the version to a newer one, preferably `1.7.3` since this is the last version before version `2.0.0` (which introduced a lot of breaking changes).

To do this, simply run `py3 -m pip uninstall discord.py; py3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]==1.7.3` if you're on Windows, or run `python3 -m pip uninstall discord.py; python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]==1.7.3` if you're on macOS or Linux.

Comment: I was using the latest version of discord.py `discord-2.2.2` i tried downgrading to 1.7.3
but still it didn't worked